# Reduce DevExpress theme dll's on deploy folder

Tags: dll, devexpress

Using the

> DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool

helps finding out the needed dll's depending on your references. In my case I have as a reference just **DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.v16.1**.

The total amount of dll's to deploy from DevExpress is 33. From those, 20 are *DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.XXX* related.

I understand that depending on the context you can have different themes, like aero, metro, win xp...

Is there any way to reduce the amount of dll's in the deploy folder.

Or

Is there any way to 'fix'/'hardcore' the theme to be used and have just one of them deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this DevExpress Thread - [Could not load file or assembly DevExpress.Xpf.Themes...](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T426052)

Starting with version 16.1, the default application theme is "**Office2016White**". Thus, it is required to add a reference to the ***DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.Office2016White.v16.1*** assembly in your project if it uses the default theme.

In addition, the default theme is now applied to standard WPF controls, not only DevExpress ones.

To switch to another theme, use the ***ApplicationThemeHelper.ApplicationThemeName*** property. The ***DevExpress.Xpf.ThemeManager.ApplicationThemeName*** property has become obsolete.

To restore the old behavior, set the ***DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ApplicationThemeHelper.UseLegacyDefaultTheme*** property to **true** before the first reference to the DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v16.1 assembly. See the example below:

```
public partial class App : Application {
    public App() {
  ApplicationThemeHelper.UseLegacyDefaultTheme = true;
    }
}
```

The value of the static Theme.Default property has been changed to Office2016White.

For the answer of you question, You can just add that theme assembly which your added controls use. If you have changed theme from different control by modifying some properties then you have to be careful about that required assemblies.

Hope this help..

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NiranjanKala. So I understand that if I set the UseLegacyDefaultTheme=true no other than Office2016White theme will load, so I can delete the other themes from deploy folder, right?